# Read input from text file in java

Tags: java

I want to read input from a text file in java. I have a text file as follows.

```
5
4
abcd
6
8
defgh
10
```

I want to read each character from file as a separate entity and work on that character individually like storing 4 in database separating abcd as a b c d  and work on them individually.

What are the various ways to do it. What is the most efficient way.

Comment: What is **one** way you've tried?

Comment: I tried to use FileReader class then
FileReader fr=new FileReader(file);
int r

while((r=fr.read())=-1)
{
Char c=(Char)r;
System.out.Println(c);

Comment: @RiteshSangwan post your code, please, so we can tell you why it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way (and short) if you use Java 7:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("path to file"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

It will put all file data to list where list item represents one row

Comment: I tried it but There is a blank line after each line when I try to print the contents of lines. Also I am not able to get first line
This is the code

`List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        for(int i=1;i<50;i++){
        System.out.println(lines.get(i));`

@Maxim Shoustin

Comment: @RiteshSangwan because you run loop from `i=1` change to `0`. about spaces: be sure that file doesnt contain empty rows

Answer (score 1):

Use read line if your file has new lines.

```
String sCurrentLine; 
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\testing.txt"));

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
}
```

Comment: I also thought about this method but how can I individually separate abcd from a string.

Comment: Once you have the string in a variable you will need to further break it into a character array. Use toCharArray();

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use each character individually, then using a Scanner might be the way to go:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SOExample {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("myfile.txt"));
    sc.useDelimiter("");
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
      String s = sc.next();
      if (s.trim().isEmpty()) {
        continue;
      }
      System.out.println(s);
    }
    sc.close();
  }

}
```

output:

```
5
4
a
b
c
d
6
8
d
e
f
g
h
1
0
```